# How to load an external js file and use their data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a react project using `create-react-app` and my current goal is to load an external js file (that is hosted in iis)  and use their data.

I'm getting this file throught a script in index.html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:5000/GetJsFile"></script>
```

Example of my js file:

```
var data = {
   vars: {
      id: ****,
      user ******,
      name: *******,
      date: *******,
   }
   //...
}
```

My **question** is: how can I use/access the data from js file inside a component of react js?

Comment: your example does not contain a `json` but `javascript`. Either export / import your js Object or call a json by an online API. Loading json files from your local file system will not work in a browser context but in node. You cannot simply add a script tag and make the src a json file...

Comment: The example you presented is not json file. It is a javascript. It defines global variable. You can use `window.data` to access it.

Comment: @messerbill sorry, it is js file, I updated the question thx

Comment: In order to follow the common ways how react apps are written nowadays you should get rid of global variables as far as possible. Usually you do not want to use the `<script>` tag as well. This question seems to be way too broad imho...You should get familiar to react's components

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @Mx.Wolf I think that it works

Comment: @messerbill but if I need to use external files, how can I access them without scripts?

Comment: no - this is definitely **not** an answer to the question. If you need to use external functions those are usually imported using `import` or `require`. Often this is also used to import libraries and stuff out off `node_modules`

Comment: @messerbill is it possible to import or require an external file?

Comment: no it's not. This is only possible using a `<script>` tag but in 99,99% of all cases there is a better solution. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @messerbill I just don't know how to use data from the third-party js file in reactJs and what is the best solution...

Comment: are you talking about `data` or about `logic / functionality`? Data will be called using `http requests` while third-party-functionality will be imported using `npm`. If your script is not available via npm you can still push it into a git repository and include it using npm

Comment: @messerbill okay, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In your utils.js page

you must change your code to this shape:

> utils page

```
const data = {
   vars: {
      id: ****,
      user ******,
      name: *******,
      date: *******,
   }
   //...
}
export default data;
```

and after that in other component that you want to use this data write this code:

```
import data from '../../../../utils';

...
console.log('data', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with loading the JSON's data from the html file directly is that it will not be available for your react code to use.

Since you are loading it from an external source, you need to use something like *fetch*, *axios* or *superagent* to retrieve it.

You can either use async/await or promises.

```
async function loadJsonFromExternal() {
    const dataFromJSON = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/GetJson');
    return dataFromJSON;
}
```

Say you have your **component.js** file with something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
export default function CoolComponent (props) {
  let myName = 'Enigma';
  useEffect(() => {
      loadJsonFromExternal()
      .then((result) => { myName = result.name });
  }, [])
  return (
     <div>My name is: {myName}</div>
  )
}
```

That would be the approach to do.

Comment: the question is not about loading json files anymore but how to import js files....